# Регулярное выражение для проверки правильности написания функции (процедуры) Pascal

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, pascal

Не могу разобраться с парсером, не могу написать регулярку проще говоря.

Нужно сделать TCP сeрвер, который принимает от клиентoв регулярные выражения и выпoлняет их вычисление. Клиенту возвращается удовлетворяет ли переданное выражение зaданному языку или нет. Обработку запросoв от клиентов нужно реализовать с использованием пула потоков.

В качестве пaрамeтров могут выступать идeнтификаторы, стрoковые константы, зaключенные в двойные кавычки и oдиночные символы, заключeнные в одинарные кавычки.

Пример строк, отправляемых клиентом серверу (без синтакс. ошибок введенные процедуры)

```
proc1('d',11,"word");
proc2('d',s,d,11,"word");
proc3("word");
```

Сервер должен дать ответ, верно ли введена процедура или нет

С синтаксическими ошибками процедуры

```
proc1(d',11,"word"); //отсутствует кавычка в начале первого параметра
proc2('d',s,d,11,word"); //отсутствует двойная кавычка в начале последнего параметра
proc3("word); //отсутствует двойная кавычка в конце последнего параметра
```

Клиент

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 904);
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            socket.Send(buffer);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Сервер

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,904));
            socket.Listen(5);
            Socket client = socket.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("New connect");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            client.Receive(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Жалкая попытка сделать парсер:

```
public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)
    {
        if ((str.Length == 0) && (str[str.Length - 1] != ')'))
        {
            haveError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int startIndex = str.IndexOf('('),
            lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf(')'),
            startIndex2 = str.LastIndexOf('('),
            lastIndex2 = str.IndexOf(')');
            if (startIndex < lastIndex && startIndex > 0 && lastIndex == str.Length - 1 &&
            startIndex == startIndex2 && lastIndex == lastIndex2)
            {
                int curr = startIndex + 1;
                while (curr < lastIndex)
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while (str[curr] != ',' && curr < lastIndex)
                    {
                        s += str[curr];
                        curr++;
                    }

                    curr++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                haveError = true;
            }
        }
        doneEvent.Set();
    }
```

Comment: А если сделать файл с определениями этих процедур, а потом просто прилеплять в правильное место присланный клиентом вызов и пытаться скомпилировать компилятором? Он умный, у него парсер, пусть у него голова и болит.

Comment: Можно детальнее?

Comment: 1) Это не делается регуляркой. 2) это называется синтаксический анализатор, очень упрощенная его версия но суть не меняет.
Можно погуглить на тему "разбор выражений", задача сходная.
Допустим если не вдаваться во все глубины языка а задеть только край, верно ли такое использование `Proc1(proc2('a'),Proc3[1],'"4"',data[1][1]);` ибо для паскаля оно вполне себе может быть верным. а к примеру такое - неверно `Proc1(proc2('a'),Proc3[1],"4",data[1][1]);`

Comment: @noname_clean, Александр предложил вам взять готовый компилятор языка паскаль и вызывать его для проверки возможности такой записи, но для такого подхода придется описать все возможные варианты процедуры со всеми возможными входными параметрами, плюс это будет гораздо более ресурсоемко нежели сделать проверку по спецификации.

Comment: Есть ли в этих строковых литаралах экранирующие последовательности? Если нет, всё просто: `^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\((?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\w+))*\);$` (необходима компиляция с `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`)

Comment: Вы пробовали мой код?

Comment: Да, не получается его запустить. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с "необходима компиляция с RegexOptions.ECMAScript"

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Подключение директивы using System.Text.RegularExpressions; не помогло, кавычки двойные мешают, сейчас буду разбираться

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\((?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|\w+))*\);$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`

Comment: Благодарю, выручили, не хочу наглеть, но можете добавить пожалуйста еще проверку на пустые кавычки одинарные и двойные?

Comment: Без примера неясно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: proc1("",3,'2');// пустой параметр в двойных кавычках, должно выдать ошибку, с одинарными тоже если пустой параметр, то ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\((?:'[^']+'|""[^""]+""|\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:'[^']+'|""[^""]+""|\w+))*\);$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)) 
{
     return false;
}
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B_a-zA-Z%5D%5Cw*%5C%28%28%3F%3A%27%5B%5E%27%5D%2B%27%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%22%7C%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*%28%3F%3A%27%5B%5E%27%5D%2B%27%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%22%7C%5Cw%2B%29%29*%5C%29%3B%5Cr%3F%24&i=proc1%28%27d%27%2C11%2C%22word%22%29%3B%0D%0Aproc2%28%27d%27%2Cs%2Cd%2C11%2C%22word%22%29%3B%0D%0Aproc3%28%22word%22%29%3B%0D%0Aproc1%28d%27%2C11%2C%22word%22%29%3B%0D%0Aproc2%28%27d%27%2Cs%2Cd%2C11%2Cword%22%29%3B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%0D%0Aproc3%28%22word%29%3B%0D%0Aproc1%28%22%22%2C3%2C%272%27%29%3B&o=m)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[_a-zA-Z]\w*` - знак подчеркивания или латинская буква, потом 0 и более цифр, букв или `_`
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|\w+)` - одно из трех:

  - `'[^']+'` - `'`, 1 и более символов, отличных от `'` (`[^']+`), а потом `'`
  - `"[^"]+"` - `"`, 1 и более символов, отличных от `"` (`[^"]+`), а потом `"`
  - `\w+` - 1 и более цифр, букв или `_`
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей группы:

  - `\s*,\s*` - запятая с 0 и более пробельными символами вокруг неё
  - `(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|\w+)` - см. выше
- `)*` - конец  незахватывающей группы, повтор 0 и более раз
- `\);` - подстрока `);`
- `$` - конец строки.

Опция `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` необходима, чтобы `\w` был равен `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.